# Сравнить два массива объектов Js

Tags: javascript

Требуется помощь в реализации задачи!
Имеем два массива:

```js
const arr = [
  {
   stackId: "1",
   name: "Ivan",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
  {
   stackId: "2",
   name: "Igor",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
  {
   stackId: "3",
   name: "Andrey",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
]

const arr2 = [
  {
   _id: "1",
   key: "active",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
  {
   _id: "2",
   key: "not active",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
  {
   _id: "3",
   key: "not active",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
```

Нужно пробежаться по всему массиву и для каждого объекта сравнить stackId из arr и _id из arr2 и если они совпадают, то в arr для проверяемого объекта нужно добавить свойство status с соответствующим значением из свойства key из массива arr2...
Исходя из примера должен получиться такой массив

```js
const result = [
  {
   stackId: "1",
   name: "Ivan",
   status: "active",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
  {
   stackId: "2",
   name: "Igor",
   status: "not active",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
  {
   stackId: "3",
   name: "Andrey",
   status: "not active",
   otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
]
```

P.S. массивы могут быть не отсортированы, так что нужно ориентироваться только на stackId и _id

Comment: А массивы так отсортированы, так что индексы всегда одинаковые или надо на `stackId` и`_id` ориентироваться?

Comment: А сами вы что-то сделали? в чем сложности возникают?

Comment: @Evgenii пробовал сделать, пока не получилось, поэтому и написал сюда за помощью)

Comment: @EzioMercer дополнил вопрос, лучше ориентироваться только на id-шники

Comment: @Evgenii не для этого написал, чтобы на словах узнать что что-то не получилось) Нужно прикладывать код, где были ваши попытки что-то сделать и показать ваш результат. А то так выглядит, что вы сами ничего не даже не пробовали, а просто скинули сюда задание, которые мы должны сделать за вас) Потому лучше всегда показываться свои попытки. Быть может вы были в шаге от "победы" и мы вам подскажем что у вас не так было

Comment: @IgorB Ещё такой вопрос: А гарантировано что для каждого элемента из `arr` найдётся соответсвующий элемент из `arr2`? И такой же вопрос в обратном порядке: А гарантировано что для каждого элемента из `arr2` найдётся соответсвующий элемент из `arr1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```js
const arr = [
  {
    stackId: "1",
    name: "Ivan",
    otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  },
  {
    stackId: "2",
    name: "Igor",
    otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  },
  {
    stackId: "3",
    name: "Andrey",
    otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
]

const arr2 = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    key: "active",
    otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    key: "not active",
    otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    key: "not active",
    otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
  }
]
//
const indexs = new Map()
arr2.forEach(el => indexs.set(el._id, el.key))
arr.map(el => {
  const key = indexs.get(el.stackId)
  if ( !key ) return el
  el.status = key
  return el
})
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{
  stackId: "1",
  name: "Ivan",
  otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
}, {
  stackId: "2",
  name: "Igor",
  otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
}, {
  stackId: "3",
  name: "Andrey",
  otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
}];

const arr2 = [{
  _id: "1",
  key: "active",
  otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
}, {
  _id: "2",
  key: "not active",
  otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
}, {
  _id: "3",
  key: "not active",
  otherInfo: "bla-bla-bla",
}];
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
  for (let y = 0; y <= arr2.length - 1; y++) {
    if (arr[i].stackId == arr2[y]._id) {
      arr[i].status = arr2[y].key;
      result[i] = {
        stackId: arr[i].stackId,
        name: arr[i].name,
        status: arr[i].status,
        otherInfo: arr2[y].otherInfo,
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

P.S. Но у Владимира красивее ответ)) Хотя и не учтён порядок элементов в элементе-объекте в результирующем массиве

Comment: Что значит не учтён порядок элементов? Что именно там в разраброску?

Comment: И у Владимира не то что ответ красивее, а у него в разы эффективнее. У вас цикл в цикле для такой простой задачи. Что значит что у вас сложность алгоритма `O(n^2)`, а у Владимира линейная сложность `O(2n)`. Что значит что для 100 элементов вам понадобится примерно (в худшем случае) 10 000 итераций, а ему всего 200

Comment: @EzioMercer, я лишь придал значение тому, что свойство `status` идёт предпоследним в элементе-объекта, что, несомненно, пустяк в сравнении с моим "громоздким" кодом.

Comment: @EzioMercer, Справедливо подмечено про эффективность